# Update value in Excel Field based on Value in another

Tags: excel

I am trying to update the value of Cell A1 to reflect the value in B1, but without using formulas in Cell A1. For Example, if the value in B1=5, then By default the value in A1 should be updated to 5. The user needs to be able to type in a number in A1 if B1 is blank, but once B1 has a value, then A1 should always reflect that value. I have tried VBA but it doesn't work. I am hoping there is a way to do this without VBA. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, there is no way without vba, any formula put in A1 would be overwritten if the user typed in A1.  You can use a third cell in which the user can put the user defined value, say C1 then the formula in A1 would be: `=IF(B1="",C1,B1)`

Comment: As always.Thanks, Scott!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible without using VBA

To copy `B1` to `A1` if `B1` isn't empty using VBA (every time a cell is changed)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B1").Value) Then
        Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Same thing but if `B1` becomes empty, it clears `A1`

```
Private clear As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B1").Value) Then
        clear = True
        Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value
    ElseIf clear = true Then
        clear = False
        Range("A1").Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ScottCraner if the first is true, it sets clear to true, if the second is true, it sets it to false so it only executes once unless the first becomes true agin

also clear is declared outside the Worksheet_Change function

Comment: Nevermind did not realize that you put it as a global variable.